# Can HTTrack download a subdirectory?

Tags: download, website, httrack

I found this really useful tool HTTrack online and I'm wondering if I can download  a subdirectory, instead of the whole website. For instance, instead of downloading www.example.com and all it's subdirectories, I'd instead download www.example.com/sub/directory and all it's subdirectories.

Comment: It's probably a simple answer, but I really don't know.

Comment: If you know the URL, yes. http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/27147/27145/index.html

Comment: I don't quite understand what that link says... But it did take me to a forum which I didn't realize there was: http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/34213/index.html so although you didn't fix my problem, you aided in helping me get closer to solving it.

Comment: I also have this question, and there still seems to be no helpful answer on the forum as of Apr 2018. If anyone can help answer this, please do so!

Answer (score 7):

So user [Michael](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36687) helped me figure this out (for Windows 7) in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43901432#43901432):

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\WinHTTrack` folder
2. `Shift + right click` in the WinHTTrack folder window and select `Open command window here`
3. Enter the following:

   ```
   httrack www.example.com/subdirectory -D -O "C:\Users\subdirectory" -M1000000000
   ```

   - Alternatively, you can type this up elsewhere, and then, when ready, copy and paste it to the `cmd` window by `right click` > `"paste"`
4. Hit `Enter` and wait....

---

Note:

- `httrack` initiates the process
- `-D` makes it so the process "can only go down into subdirs"

  - (i.e., it prevents copying any higher level directories above `www.example.com/subdirectory`)
- `-O` tells machine to save the output to the local directory listed after `-O`

  - Don't forget to wrap the address in `""`, especially if your address has spaces
- `-M` (optional): limits maximum overall size that can be uploaded/scanned (--max-size[=N]) [in *bytes*]

---

You can see more help on the [Httrack Users Guide (3.10)](https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html).

- Simple instructions for the WinTTrack GUI can be found [here](https://www.httrack.com/html/step4.html)

Comment: Thats Nice!. Seedhi baat no Bakwas. Clear hai

Answer (score 0):

example command

```
httrack -v "http://thissite.com"  -O thissite.com "+*.thissite.com.com/*"
```

this scan rule download all subdreictory

```
"+*.thissite.com.com/*"
```

if download only subdomain

```
"subdomain.thissite.com.com/*"
```